# How to set the a redelivery time for RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp, rabbitmq-exchange, node-amqplib

I'm trying to understand how to set the redelivery time for basic.nacked messages. Some important info is that I'm using quorum queues with a redelivery amount of 5 times. Consider the following scenario:

**What is happening Now:**

1. Producer sends message: Message X
2. Consumer handles Message X and runs into an error, in the error handler I use basic.nack()
3. Message is resent to original queue. Consumer immediately handles that task again.
4. This process repeats until the redelivery amount has been reached and then it's dead-lettered.

**What I actually want:**

I want the message that is requeued to wait a few seconds (3-5 sec or something) before it's once again handled by a consumer. I want to do this due to the fact that I'm using OCC & there are instances where delaying the message redelivery solves consistency issues. (for the people wondering why in god's name I need this).

I was able to do this with NATS streaming server, but I don't know how to implement it with rabbitMQ.

Additional info: I'm using amqplib (typescript) as the client and prefetch is set to 10 globally. I'm using AWS MQ for Rabbit as my rabbitMQ host

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i know, there isn't a way to add [RabbitMQ Delayed Message Plugin](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-delayed-message-exchange) to AWS MQ.
You can:

- create a new `dead_letter_queue` with `x-message-ttl` option, with value you need (3-5 secs)
- for this `dead_letter_queue` dead letter exchange will be your original exchange
- create `dead_letter_exchange` connected with `dead_letter_queue`

Workflow:

1. Consumer `nack` message
2. Message goes to `dead_letter_exchange`
3. From `dead_letter_exchange` it goes to `dead_letter_queue`
4. In `dead_letter_queue` message waits `x-message-ttl` time
5. Message marks as dead and goes to your original exchange (and then to your original queue)

[image]

Comment: Yeah, I scowered the docs for the redelivery plugin inside MQ. But sadly enough config files are for some reason only for the amqp engine & not the rabbit engine. I was thinking of something similar you proposed here. I'm going to do what you propose, but with a rollback queue as well I suppose.